# Unable to boot after update to linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic

Tags: 12.04, kernel, update-manager

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Intel-based computer.
I ran the update package for a new release Linux and it seemed to be successful, but when rebooting, I was unable to boot. I booted to a previous version of Linux and tried to remove the package using
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic
but got an error saying it couldn't be removed because of dependencies.

How can I re-install the latest version of Linux, or, if that is impossible, make the previous version the default, so I don't get a stack dump when I try to reboot?

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic (from .../linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic_3.13.0-39.66~precise1_i386.deb) ...
Done.
Preparing to replace linux-image-generic-lts-trusty 3.13.0.37.32 (using .../linux-image-generic-lts-trusty_3.13.0.39.34_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-image-generic-lts-trusty ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.13.0-39.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-39 (from .../linux-headers-3.13.0-39_3.13.0-39.66~precise1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic (from .../linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic_3.13.0-39.66~precise1_i386.deb) ...
Preparing to replace linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty 3.13.0.37.32 (using .../linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty_3.13.0.39.34_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty ...
Preparing to replace linux-generic-lts-trusty 3.13.0.37.32 (using .../linux-generic-lts-trusty_3.13.0.39.34_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-generic-lts-trusty ...
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic (3.13.0-39.66~precise1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
```

Comment: One thing from my experience never update for new release from old . Just do the backup of your files and reinstall fresh.

Comment: Thanks Hackaholic! I'm a desktop user, not a hacker, so I use the GUI update-manager and basically let it do what it suggests. It seems like linux kernels are released every week or so, and having to back up and restore every time feels incredibly painful and time-consuming, when all I want to do is keep my software up to date. For that reason, and because my internet connection is not fast, I have been holding off on upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, since 12.04 is supported until 2018 in theory. Do you know what to do about the "possible missing firmware" messages?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enter in the terminal from previous kernel this:

```
 sudo apt-get purge -y --force-yes linux-shim-amd64 shim* linux-generic
```

and it might work fine or you can type in the terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yaunnubuntu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Sorry to be ignorant. Are these two suggestions alternatives to each other? or should they both be run in sequence? Does purge remove all existing linux kernels or just the latest? Why is AMD64 referenced? If mine is Intel Atom, is that the right command?

Comment: Try first one if dos not work try the next, and it only purge the last one.